# Adding custom ImageButton control to Windows Phone project

Tags: c#, windows-phone, imagebutton

I'm trying to put a image as a button background, i see a lot of questions about this, and the better way seems to be subclassing button to create a custom ImageButton.

Anyway i tried using ImageBrush to set the image as button background, but it isn't working, something like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = home;
b.Background = ib;
```

And setting an image as content:

```
Image i = new Image();
i.Source = home;
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = home;
```

Then i saw a [ImageButton class](http://imagebuttonwpf.codeplex.com/), i downloaded and added to project.

But i cant compile it

```
    static ImageButton() {
  DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
}

 public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSize", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(30.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Basically i'm getting this errors:

```
'System.Windows.DependencyProperty' does not contain a definition for 'OverrideMetadata' and no extension method 'OverrideMetadata' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'FrameworkPropertyMetadata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The name 'FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions' does not exist in the current context
```

Someone could tell me how to solve this? or if i'm doing something wrong putting the background image or a way to make it, just need a button with a image filling it, without padding or margin or borders.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a button with an image as a background, try this

```
<Grid>
    <Button BorderThickness="0">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="your_image.jpg"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
<Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `ImageBrush`.

```
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/SmallLogo.png"));
Button1.Background = brush;
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327074/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-button-on-runtime) thread.

Hope it helps!