# Change the image of buttons when pressed in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I set image for button with a code like this

```
<Button x:Name="btToBackgroundPage" Click="toBackground_Click" Width="250" Height="100" BorderThickness="0">
    <Image Source="/Assets/Image/A.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

So when i click it, i want to change the Image within button to something like "B.png"

I know i can do it by using pressed event of button and change source of image , but my app have many buttons like that and I just want to know if is there anyway to set that in xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do that in `xaml` itself, because somehow you got to have an event handler for your `image` click event to change the image source of the `button`.

[How to change the background image of button on runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327074/) would be helpful.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So with each button I have to used two event , pressed and leave pressed to just change the image ?? and with all my buttons in app ?? MS should change this on WP9 :(

Comment: If you really wanted to do anything when you leave the button click, then you can go with both the events. Otherwise just a click  or a tap event would do. Why don't you have a common template for all the buttons, so that you can apply it to each and every one of them. But functionality wise if you have to do different ones for every button then you have to handle them separately.

Answer (score 0):

This may look little bit complex. But It works fine.

XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="11,0,12,0" Background="Black">

            <Button x:Name="b1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="208,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MouseLeave" Tag="b1">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="b1bg"  ImageSource="/Assets/WP_20140902_001.jpg" />
                </Button.Background>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedHighlightBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background }" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                                <Border x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="b2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MouseLeave" Tag="b2">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="b2bg"  ImageSource="/Assets/WP_20140902_001.jpg"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedHighlightBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background }" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >
                                <Border x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

CS::

```
private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button temp = sender as Button;

    var actionString = temp.Tag;
    var value = this.FindName(actionString + "bg");
    ((ImageBrush)value).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/WP_20140902_001.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}

private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button temp = sender as Button;
    var actionString = temp.Tag;
    var value= this.FindName(actionString + "bg");
    ((ImageBrush)value).ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/splash_480_720.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```